# Нужна библиотека для работы с изображениями на Python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, обработка-изображений

Вот такая задача появилась: необходимо поверх одного изображения наложить другое (получить третье изображение).
Имеется ли такая библиотека на Python?

Comment: Практически любая библиотека для обработки изображений на это способна к примеру `pillow`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите свои изображения и расскажите лучше, что на что вы хотите наложить, и что в итоге хотите получить.

Comment: Показать не могу, это общий замысел такой, будет что то вроде, что одно изображение - рамка для другого. Либо .png с прозрачным фоном поверх другого изображения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже писали: pillow, opencv-python3...